# C# Multithreading with Lock

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am a beginner to C#. I am taking a look at sample of multithreading.

I have set up a multithreaded call to method `DoTransactions()`, which in turn will generate a random number as `amount`, and call method `Withdraw()` to deduct `salary` by `amount`.

1) What I don't understand is that why the writer chose to lock Object `thisLock` instead of locking salary? I saw some others also lock thread in this way by declaring an object and locking it.

2) Sometimes I cannot debug the methods called when the other threads were running. (by pressing F10/F11). (e.g. methods `Withdraw()`). Any reason for this?

```
Department dep = new Department(1000); 
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(dep.DoTransactions));   //set up 1000 threads.

class Department
    {
        private Object thisLock = new Object();
        int salary = 10000;

        int Withdraw(int amount)
        {
            lock (thisLock)
            {
                if (salary >= amount)
                {
                    salary = salary - amount;
                    return amount;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: this code doesn't even compile

Comment: yep, your `int Withdraw()` method will not compile because there's a missing return statement

Answer (score 2):

1. You can lock only on class (reference type) while Salary is an int which is value type.

MSDN :

> The expression of a lock statement must denote a value of a
>   reference-type. No implicit boxing conversion (Section 6.1.5) is ever
>   performed for the expression of a lock statement, and thus it is a
>   compile-time error for the expression to denote a value of a
>   value-type.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664735(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664735%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

1. What do you mean you can't debug? Probably the debugger jumps between threads.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I start 100 threads at the same time running method "Withdraw" by pressing F11, will I still be able to go through the method line by line 100 times?

Comment: Yes. To understand this better open the "threads" window (while debugging: Debug->Windows->Threads) in Visual studio and you'll see that the debugger will switch threads.

Answer (score 1):

When debugging multithreaded applications use breakpoints  to force looking at specific code lines. You can not rely on your stepping into and stepping over to work sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your second question:

It may be that you need to first choose "break all" (click the Break All button) to stop running all threads, and then go to "Debug|Windows|Threads" to see a list of all the threads you can debug. (Each one has a separate stack frame, of course.)

From there you can double-click a thread to see if there's any source code for it. (Some will be "internal" threads that you didn't start, and these won't have source code you can see. Just keep clicking the threads until you find an interesting one. ;)

Other than that, set breakpoints in code which the thread you're interested in will execute.

Answer (score 0):

The lock is used so that only 1 thread will access that bit of code at any time. And to enable the sync between the threads they must take turns locking an object which is commonly available to all threads.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But why locking a member object(thislock) will lock all other member variables(salary) in that class(Department)? Also can I use "lock (Department)" instead of using "lock (thisLock)"?

Comment: because you need to pass a reference type to the lock, an instance of a class, then the execution of that code will be one thread at a time

Answer (score 0):

What you put in a `lock` statement (like `lock (thisLock)`) is **not the data being locked**. That cannot be the case if your think about it: If you wanted to modify two variables, which one would you put in the `lock`? (Answer: No answer exists. Impossible.).

Instead, you put in a reference to an object that will always be locked on **by convention** when accessing data that is logically protected by the lock.

Comment: In that case there is only one variable being changed. The real reason in that particular case is because you can't lock a value type.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But why locking a member object(thislock) will lock all other member variables(salary) in that class(Department)?

Comment: Also can I use "lock (Department)" instead of using "lock (thisLock)"?

Comment: @TsuiJohn I tries to clarify this: locking something does not lock data by itself. It is just a convention. Only if all readers and writers obey, the locking scheme works.